# Send user recordings from digital piano to PC

Tags: piano, recording, midi, cubase

I've managed to connect my digital piano to my PC through MIDI USB and the notes that I play live are recorded correctly. However, I also want to move recordings I make on the piano independently to the PC later. When replaying stored songs on the piano, they are not being sent to the PC like the live ones. What exactly am I doing wrong?

My digital piano didn't come with any software and I haven't to managed to find something that works.

The piano I'm using is Thomann DP 95 and the recording software is Cubase

Comment: Are you using a USB/MIDI interface, or a simple USB cable to the piano's USB port?

Comment: I have connected my pc directly to the digital piano through a MIDI / USB cable

Answer (score 1):

A MIDI cable is usable only for sending MIDI messages in real time. The manual does not mention any setting that would enable sending messages when playing a stored song.

To be able to access the internal files of the device, connect it to the PC with a plain USB cable.

Comment: With the USB cable (one end in the piano USB port and the other in the PC), the PC does not recognize the piano as a file system (can't access it like a traditional flash drive). The only thing going through the USB cable seems to be the live notes that I am playing on the piano (using Cubase). Also I can replay notes on the piano from the virtual keyboard in Cubase

Comment: See section 8.22 of the manual; do you get "PC Link"?

Comment: I've read the manual but it is very incomplete in this respect. When I connect the piano to the PC via usb there is no "PC Link" message BUT a USB icon appears on the bottom of the piano display and cubase can receive and send live notes to/from the piano this way.

Just not the songs already recorded...

Comment: So the manual appears to by lying. Ask Thomann, or find out who actually built the piano.

Answer (score 0):

In order to transfer User Songs from the Thomann Dp-95 to the PC you need a software called "pootute".  With this program you can also convert and transfer Standard Midifiles to the Dp-95.

Since the software isn't supplied with the Dp-95 you will have to download it here:

https://www.medeli.com.hk/downloads

If the program doesn't start properly, saying that it can't be executed due to a side by side configuration issue try the following:

Goto the folder "C:/Progam Files (x86) /pootute" and execute the "vcredist_x86.exe" .